# How to avoid refresh in server side Java

Tags: java, servlets

Please consider this scenario: User should send some files to server and every user has a id. Every user must send the files once, not twice. If a user sends the files and he want to send them again, the file uploading page won't be shown to him. But there is a problem: the uploading process takes time and when the files are being uploaded, user can refresh the page and the page is shown to him (because the files has been not uploaded yet) and then he can upload files again and again!
The client side code using jsp and I cant change it. Now I want to prevent refreshing page in server side. For this purpose, I used a middle page: when a user want to see the file uploading page he goes to this middle page (servlet), this middle servlet puts a flag into user's session and redirect him to file uploading servlet. The file uploading servlet checks the flag and if it exist, the page is shown to him and then flag will be removed. Whenever a user try to refresh the file uploading page, the flag doesn't exist and he will be redirected to an error page.
This was my solution, but it has a serious problem: when user is redirected from middle servlet to file uploading servlet, its request and response will be destroyed and I cant access his request (The user send me some information with his request and I need those in file uploading servlet).

1 - Is there a way to clone request object? (so that I can put in session and after redirect, I can retrieve that)

2- If the answer is no, Is there a better solution for my problem?

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

**Edit:**
Please note that I don't want to save the request parameters/attributes into session.

Comment: I think it would be more cohesive to include a validation in the upload servlet (or a service). If the file is already saved, an exception is thrown.
NOTE: Because Servlets are not thread safe, synchronize the block that performs the validation.

Another tip would use a specific exception and then define its in web.xml to Container foward to a specific error page.

Comment: @HenriqueFernandesCipriano: That's the right way, but unfortunately I use an engine for the file storing and its process, and the engine picks up the files with a few seconds delay and then, i can perform such a validation. Thanks for your useful reply

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.stop();` in your code.

Comment: This is the worst idea.